# To create application in ios and android

Tags: android, ios

I want to create such a app in which user click on app button he will see all his app and that will be store in cloud by which mobile space will be reduced and performance will be increase.Suppose user is using whatapp his history will be maintain in database and cache of that history will be there in his mobile.can it be possible to create it. need your help

Comment: It is possible you are already using that kind of apps. Apps that require internet connection save users login credentials on their servers which can be a cloud server. What kind of help do you need?

Comment: Try "Parse" or "FIrebase" they provide connectivity for your app with cloud database

Comment: This question is extraordinarily broad and unspecific.  More problematic is that the user can't even figure out where to begin because [they are trying to eat an elephant the wrong way](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/).  This isn't really a great starting point for enlisting assistance.